# XrayImportFeatureBuilder Jenkins integration makes empty .zip after finding feature files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira-xray

I have XRAY integrated with Jenkins and our Jira instance following the documentation [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Jenkins#IntegrationwithJenkins-Cucumber(%22standard%22workflow)) I have no issues with XrayImportBuilder to import execution results or XrayExportBuilder to export scenarios from JIRA to run on jenkins.

When i use **XrayImportFeatureBuilder** to import scenarios into Jira, my .zip file remains empty and the import fails.

```
stage('Xray import feature files to Jira') {
            steps {
                step([$class        : 'XrayImportFeatureBuilder',
                      serverInstance: automatedTestConstants.SERVER_INSTANCE,
                      projectKey    : 'TEST',
                      folderPath    : "${env.WORKSPACE}/${JOB_BASE_NAME}/src/test/resources/features"
                ])
            }
        }
```

the Jenkins trace shows

```
File: d:/JenkinsBuild/workspace/xxx/src/test/resources/features
File found: d:\JenkinsBuild\workspace\xxx\src\test\resources\features\xxx.feature
File found: d:\JenkinsBuild\workspace\xxx\src\test\resources\features\yyy.feature
Creating zip to import feature files. This may take a while if you have a big number of files.
File: d:/JenkinsBuild/workspace/xxx/src/test/resources/features
Waiting 10 seconds to finish the zip before making the request
{"testIssues":[],"preConditionIssues":[],"message":"Error parsing feature file\n"}
XRAY_IS_REQUEST_SUCCESSFUL: true
XRAY_RAW_RESPONSE: {"testIssues":[],"preConditionIssues":[],"message":"Error parsing feature file\n"}
XRAY_TESTS: 
XRAY_ISSUES_MODIFIED: 
XRAY_TEST_EXECS: 
Temporary file: d:/JenkinsBuild/workspace/xxx/xray_cucumber_features.zip deleted
Response: (200) {"testIssues":[],"preConditionIssues":[],"message":"Error parsing feature file\n"}
Successfully imported Feature files
```

If i manually use the api to import a zip containing the same features, i get no errors.

Comment: My recommendation is to reach out Xray support team (https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) so they can analyze it in more detail. Previously the Jenkins plugin submitted each .feature file one by one, but nowadays not sure about the actual implementation

Comment: in contact. appears related to https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAYJENKINS-137